# Trouble connecting to Microsoft SQL Server with Windows Authentication

Tags: sql-server, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am building a flask project for internal use at my company. I start by using flask and postgre and used sqlalchemy and set up that connection using the model formats like below:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

app.config.from_object('config')

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

and that worked well. Now for security reasons we are switching to using Microsoft SQL Server with window authentication on an IIS server but i am having a lot of trouble connecting.
I changed the database URI to

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "mssql+pyodbc://server/database"
```

I've checked the SQL Sever configuration and I am pretty sure that is correct. However I get the error

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: server closed the connection unexpectedly
        This probably means the server terminated abnormally
        before or while processing the request.
```

I have researched this issue and have used the pool_pre_ping solution but I get the same error (shown below)

```
SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS = {"pool_pre_ping": True}
```

I have seen a lot of answers around this stuff that use the sqlalchemy.engine stuff but if possible I was hoping to use all of the db.models I have already written out but if that's not possible I can rewrite some stuff. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Authentication will become a problem when you deploy to production. I recommend creating a SQL user to connect to your database.

Try this connection string:

```
mssql+pyodbc://<UID>:<PWD>@<SERVER>/<DATABASE>?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server;Trusted_Connection=no
```

Also make sure you've installed `pyodbc` [msft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-1-configure-development-environment-for-pyodbc-python-development?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
pip install pyodbc
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. i tried the above connection string and am now getting a " could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)" any thoughts? Also, could you explain what you mean about creating a sql user to connect to db.

Comment: WIndows Auth users a user on your domain e.g. 'Domain\User', a SQL user is created on the SQL Server  [see](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: If you want to use Windows Auth, remove the `UID` and `PWD` from the connection string and change `trusted_connection=no` to `Trusted_connection=yes`.

Comment: I am unfortunately getting the same error when trying to use windows auth

Comment: Ignore Flask & SQLAlchemy for now. Can you connect to you database with `pyodbc`?. Follow the example from [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pyodbc?view=sql-server-ver15). Once you've figured out the correct connection string, use that in your app.

Comment: I am able to establish a working connection with the following: engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://@<server>/<db>?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server;Trusted_Connection=yes') but that same connection string yields an error when I use it as my DATABASE_URI. Worst case scenario I could rewrite everything for the sql_engine but I was hoping to avoid that